# how to hide the other apps of my company in play google

Tags: android, hide

I want to hide the other apps of my company, 
for example when you enter to the page of my application you find link to my company, I want to delete this link
also in the button of the page you find (More from developer) link, I want also to delete this link.
I want like this company: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.goldesel&referrer=adjust_reftag%3DcIlQp0wZeyVOM%26utm_source%3DInviteFriend

Comment: It is not possible

Comment: no, it is possible you can try that one link, i like to do like him

Comment: That is because he don't have another app

Comment: what about his companys link or description? he dont have company?

Comment: If you mean the developer page, that is optional

Comment: now i have created my developer page, i dont found any thing optional in the page, i found (Delete Page
If you delete your developer page, users who select your apps' "More by Developer" section will only see a list of your apps instead.).

Comment: can you please explain which thing is optional?

Answer (score 1):

The developer page is optional, if you have one it will appear, if not it  is going to appear More of and the name of the developer